# Laravel 4 - view query

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I have 3 views (which display settings for each): Users, Groups, Options
Each of these views is successfully rendering, using the below.  The controller passes the database info into each view.

```
    @extends('master')

    @section('main-title')
        Title
    @stop

    @section('main-content')
        // All the divs, content etc (working fine)
    @stop
```

I also have one more view: Settings

The idea of this view is simple, to be an overview of all the settings from the Users, Groups and Options.  So essentially I'm trying to pull together each of the 3 views 'main-content' output, and put it within the `@section('main-content')` within my Settings view.  However I have no idea how.

The only option I can think of is to duplicate the content within the Settings view (index function) - however this will cause issues when I want to change something as I'll need to do it in two templates.

My controller:

```
public function index()
{
    $users = User::all();
    $options = Option::all();
    $groups = Group::all();
    return View::make('layouts.settings', array('users' => $users, 'options' => $options, 'groups' => $groups));
}

public function users()
{
    $users = User::all();
    return View::make('layouts.settings.users', array('users' => $users));
}

public function options()
{
    $options = Option::all();
    return View::make('layouts.settings.options', array('options' => $options));
}

public function groups()
{
    $groups = Group::all();
    return View::make('layouts.settings.groups', array('groups' => $groups));
}
```

Is there anyway, I can say within my Settings view: include the content within 'main-content' from the following views (Users, Groups, Options).  Or, use nested view which I have tried but cannot get working.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried `View::make('your view')->nest('child', 'child.view.name')`? In the `your view` view, you can then use `$child` to output the child view.

Comment: Tried it: http://paste.laravel.com/xZl Not entirely sure what's going on... but I'm probably being stupid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go - may need fine-tuning: http://paste.laravel.com/xZr